# How to access Angular's Optional Configuration Object for $http.get in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have a URL that looks like this:

example.com/users/34/

I want for Angular to be able to take this ID (34) and make a call to my ASP.net server to grab information about that user.

As per Angular's documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) I am thinking I should be able to do something like this in order to achieve that:

```
$http.get("/api/users/", { UserID: 34 } ).
success(function (user, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(user);
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

But I cannot manage to write an ASP.net function that is able to grab the `UserID` variable. Here's what my C# function looks like at the moment:

```
[Route("api/users")]
public HttpResponseMessage getUser()
{
  // do some stuff... but where is UserID? I can't find it in the header etc
}
```

When I set up a break point, that function fires successfully, but I cannot get UserID. Looking around and can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Any ideas?

### --- Update ---

I've confirmed that this works:

Inside my Angular file:

```
$http.get("/api/users/?UserID=34" ).
success(function (user, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(user);
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Inside my C# file:

```
[Route("api/users")]
public HttpResponseMessage getUser( int UserID )
{
  // yay! UserID now equals 34
}
```

But what I would *like* to do instead of passing the variable as part of the URL string, is pass it as an *Optional configuration object* (as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get).

That's what I am asking help with.

Comment: a quick google search and `Request.Querystring("UserID")` would be how you get that value in ASP

Comment: @Ronnie For me, Request does not have a method of QueryString. Why would that be?

Comment: I might be confused, but are you wanting to get the value in ASP? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: I think you are confused with the default routing and parameter names. By default `example.com/users/34/` like url expect a parameter which is called `id`, not `UserID`. If you change `public HttpResponseMessage getUser()` to `public HttpResponseMessage getUser(int UserID)` it might help. But I am not sure if this conflicts with the `example.com/users/34/` routing.

Comment: @Ronnie Exactly. Need it inside that `getUser()` method.

Comment: @Stefan My API call returns a 404 if I add a parameter of type `int` to my `getUser()` method. Adding it breaks the connection.

Comment: Alternatively you could try: `public HttpResponseMessage getUser(int id)` in combination with `$http.get("/api/users/34" )`.

Comment: @Stefan In case you missed my comment above, I've tried that but it's resulting in a 404. ;( In your proposed solution, how would Angular be passing that integer value? As part of the URL string, or part of the header?

Comment: In that case in the URL. It is part of the default routing in .net's web.api. But I see you have fixed it :)

Comment: @Stefan Eh, I have, though not in the proper way. Any ideas on how to do this using Angular's Optional configuration object?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. To be honest, I can't help you with that. I am not sure if that the intended way to use it, but I am not an angular js expert.